# pyAudioAnalysis, Tuple index out of range

Tags: python, audio, tuples, indexoutofrangeexception, pyaudioanalysis

So I am trying to make a rudimentary emotion classifier using the [pyAudioAnalysis library](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis), and I have collected a small datasample to test if it works. my code is as following:

```
from pyAudioAnalysis import audioAnalysis as aA   

aA.trainClassifierWrapper('svm', False,
                      ["C:\Users\gover_000\Desktop\Angry",
                      "C:\Users\gover_000\Desktop\Happy",
                      "C:\Users\gover_000\Desktop\Sad",
                      "C:\Users\gover_000\Desktop\Scared",
                      "C:\Users\gover_000\Desktop\Neutral"],
                      "testSVM")
```

If I execute this, it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-7-2e5393432e89> in <module>()
  5                       "C:\Users\gover_000\Desktop\Scared",
  6                       "C:\Users\gover_000\Desktop\Neutral"],
----> 7                       "testSVM")

C:\Users\gover_000\Documents\GitHub\Emotion-Recognition-Prototype\pyAudioAnalysis\audioAnalysis.pyc in trainClassifierWrapper(method, beatFeatures, directories, modelName)
     88         raise Exception("At least 2 directories are needed")
     89     aT.featureAndTrain(directories, 1, 1, aT.shortTermWindow, aT.shortTermStep,
---> 90                        method.lower(), modelName, computeBEAT=beatFeatures)
     91 
     92 

C:\Users\gover_000\Documents\GitHub\Emotion-Recognition-Prototype\pyAudioAnalysis\audioTrainTest.pyc in featureAndTrain(listOfDirs, mtWin, mtStep, stWin, stStep, classifierType, modelName, computeBEAT, perTrain)
    275     featureNames = ["features" + str(d + 1) for d in range(numOfFeatures)]
    276 
--> 277     writeTrainDataToARFF(modelName, features, classNames, featureNames)
    278 
    279     for i, f in enumerate(features):

C:\Users\gover_000\Documents\GitHub\Emotion-Recognition-Prototype\pyAudioAnalysis\audioTrainTest.pyc in writeTrainDataToARFF(modelName, features, classNames, featureNames)
   1097     for c, fe in enumerate(features):
   1098         for i in range(fe.shape[0]):
-> 1099             for j in range(fe.shape[1]):
   1100                 f.write("{0:f},".format(fe[i, j]))
   1101             f.write(classNames[c]+"\n")

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I know  `shape[1]` is supposed to return the columns of an array dimension. 
but why does it return an error here

Comment: Probably because `fe` is a vector, not a matrix. So the question to research is why is one of your features 1-dimensional -- please consider tagging the question with the library name rather than `tuples` or `IndexError`.

Comment: Okay. And I couldn't tag it with the library name, since it doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I found the problem.

The problem was that one of my classifiers didn't have enough files, it needed atleast 2. so after adding more it worked again!

Answer (score 0):

The same issue could be due to different number of files inside training folders
For ex:

```
+Training
  +Bubble - 6 files
  +glass - 6 files
  +bounce - 8 files
```

Then It would also generate the same error because it can not generate the desired matrix of arrays( using `dirsWavFeatureExtraction` function inside `audioFeatureExtraction.py`).

The solution I found is there should be the same number of files inside training folders

Resolved Example:

```
+Training
  +Bubble - 6 files
  +glass - 6 files
  +bounce - 6 files
```